# Dictionary Inherited through ICollection interface, but don't implement all the members

Tags: c#, dictionary, inheritance, interface, implementation

In my current implementation, I was trying to create custom class inherited by `IDictionary<string, Object>` interface.

While implementation, I have to implement the below property

```
IsReadOnly { get; } part of  ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> interface.
```

So while doing this I came across below scenario,

I am not seeing that `IsReadOnly` Property in  `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` (.NET built in class) class, then how property implementation of `ReadOnly` in not exists in `Dictionary` class as this class is also inherited through `ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` interface.

I have same query regarding `CopyTo` method also.

This is just my conceptual question.

Comment: The interface **is** implemented on `Dictionary`, however you see it only when you cast your map to an `ICollection<T>`, becaue the interface is implemented **explicitely**.

Comment: What problem do you want to solve with your own implementation of `IDictionary<T1,T2>`? --- if you *really* want to do that, you might want to look at https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property **is** implemented on `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. The reason you don´t see it on your instance is the way [**how** the member is implemented](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs):

```
bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>.IsReadOnly {
    get { return false; }
}
```

The qualifier in front of the member-name indicates an [**explicit** implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation). This means you can access this member only when *explicitely* referring to that type by casting to it:

```
var readOnly = ((ICollection<MyType>)myMap.IsReadOnly;
```